# Vector Product Equation

Tags: vectors

I am trying to solve a problem from Hughston's and Tod's Introduction to General Relativity.
However, I am stuck.
This is the problem:
Solve of $X$ and $Y$:
$$aX_i+bY_i=P_i$$
$$\epsilon_{ijk}X_jY_k=Q_i$$

I was able to deduce an equation by contracting the first equation with $\epsilon$ and in addition once with $X$ and once with $Y$. I then obtain the following equations:

$$\epsilon_{ijk}P_jY_k=aQ_i$$
$$\epsilon_{ijk}P_jX_k=-bQ_i$$

I am stuck here. These two equations can be solved, but upto an additional term as far as I know, by again taking the vector product with $P$.
Then I obtain from the first equation:
$$a\epsilon_{lim}Q_iP_m=Y_lP_mP_m-P_lY_mP_m$$
This is an equation which depends only on $Y$, but both a single component all other components (in the scalar product with P$ are present.
I think this can be solved easily by writing out all components because then it is just a linear system of three equations, but there must be a more elegant way using index notation. But I am not sure how. Any hints or help is appreciated.